# Creating a new alert cause "List does not exist."

Tags: sharepoint-server, alert

I have a script that create alerts for specific document libraries in multiple webs. It work with sharepoint-server cmdlet and is aimed at SharePoint 2013. I tested the script with a test library and user with no issue at all.

```
#----------------------------------------------------------[Declarations]----------------------------------------------------------

# Site where the alerts will be added, all the subsite will be handled 
$siteToHandleUrl = "A Valid Url"

# Email that will recieve all the alerts
$emailToAlert = "A Valid Email"

# Lists where alerts will be added 
$listsToHandle = @("A Valid List Name")

#-----------------------------------------------------------[Execution]------------------------------------------------------------

$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity $siteToHandleUrl
$webs = $web.Site.AllWebs | Where-Object {$_.Url -like "$siteToHandleUrl*"}
$user = $web.EnsureUser($emailToAlert)
$existingAlerts = $user.Alerts.Title
if ($null -eq $existingAlerts) {
    $existingAlerts = @()
}
$addedAlerts = @()

foreach ($web in $webs) {
    Write-Host "Handling $($web.Title)"
    $lists = $web.Lists

    foreach ($listToHandle in $listsToHandle) {
         $alertName = "Automated Alert for $($list.Title) in $($web.Title)"
         $list = $web.Lists[$listToHandle]

        if (-not $existingAlerts.Contains($alertName)) {
            Write-Host "Adding alert for $($list.Title)"
           
            $newAlert = $user.Alerts.Add()
            $newAlert.Title = $alertName
            $newAlert.AlertType=[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAlertType]::List
            $newAlert.List = $list
            $newAlert.DeliveryChannels = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAlertDeliveryChannels]::Email
            $newAlert.EventType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventType]::All
            $newAlert.AlertFrequency = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAlertFrequency]::Daily
            $newAlert.Update()
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I try this script for the actual librairies, I get this error message on the `$newAlert.Update()` :

```
Exception calling "Update" with "0" argument(s): "List does not exist.
The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user."
```

Yet the library do exist and the object is literally coming from the web. Debugging show that `$user` has a valid user and `$list` has the list object. If I go the SharePoint site, I can add manually a new alert with no issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. Turn out that the way you obtain the user is very important :

```
...
foreach ($web in $webs) {
    Write-Host "Handling $($web.Title)"
    $lists = $web.Lists
    $user = $web.EnsureUser($emailToAlert)

    foreach ($listToHandle in $listsToHandle) {
         $alertName = "Automated Alert for $($list.Title) in $($web.Title)"
         $list = $web.Lists[$listToHandle]

        if (-not $existingAlerts.Contains($alertName)) {
            Write-Host "Adding alert for $($list.Title)"
           
            $newAlert = $user.Alerts.Add()
            $newAlert.Title = $alertName
...
```

You must get your user for each web you are handling. The object the `EnsureUser` is different depending on the web you are calling. In this case the `$user.Alerts` collection is only a collection of the alerts for the specified web. So if you try to add to this collection an alert on a list that is not in the web, it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your whole script, it seems you did not define the variable `$listsToHandle`.

```
Write-Host "Handling $($web.Title)"
    $lists = $web.Lists

    foreach ($listToHandle in $listsToHandle) {
         $alertName = "Automated Alert for $($list.Title) in $($web.Title)"
         $list = $web.Lists[$listToHandle]
```

As it is not defined before, in the foreach part in fact you have not lists to loop and I guess that is the reason console returns error "List does not exist".

And if seems you haven't defined `$list` before you use it in `$alertName`

Comment: The second point is a valid overlook. But no, this is not the whole script and `$user` and `$list` are properly populated. I'm going to update the post to be more concise.